# dropbox saver not working

Tags: javascript, dropbox

I want use dropbox saver button but it works just for example file in [documents](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver)

It's not working for any other direct links.(return: "This Download attempt timed out")
Is error from dropbox or ... ?

my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="urz05zr6ho1rnri"></script>

<a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/deroi5nwm6u7gdf/advice.png" class="dropbox-saver"></a>

<a href="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/pelfusion/paper-cut-social/256/Facebook-icon.png" class="dropbox-saver"></a>
```

this code can upload `advice.png`.(example in saver doc)
but can't upload `Facebook-icon.png`.(my example file)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer
Error was from dropbox.
details: https://blog.dropbox.com/2014/01/back-up-and-running/